# How to hide ID From SEO Friendly URL

Tags: c#, regex, url

I used this blog for reference for getting the SEO friendly URL,

> https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/generate-seo-friendly-urls-aspnet-mvc/

What i am getting right now is this,

> localhost:51630/blog/2-my-name-is-ajo

What I need is like this format.

> localhost:51630/blog/my-name-is-ajo

Need to remove the id from ie (2) in the url.how can i hide id from url, but i need id for getting data from database,

Here is the rote,config file i write

```
routes.Add("BlogContent", new SeoFriendlyRoute("blog/{id}",
        new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Blog", action = "DisplayContent" }),
        new MvcRouteHandler()));
```

Also the code for Generate Slug is given below,

```
 public string GenerateSlug()
    {
        string phrase = string.Format("{0}-{1}", ContentId, DisplayURL);

        string str = RemoveAccent(phrase).ToLower();
        // invalid chars           
        str = Regex.Replace(str, @"[^a-z0-9\s-]", "");
        // convert multiple spaces into one space   
        str = Regex.Replace(str, @"\s+", " ").Trim();
        // cut and trim 
        str = str.Substring(0, str.Length <= 45 ? str.Length : 45).Trim();
        str = Regex.Replace(str, @"\s", "-"); // hyphens   
        return str;
    }
```

Comment: The short answer - you can't. If you need the 2, you need it. It needs to come from _somewhere_. So either you need to pass it via the URL, or it needs to be able to be derived from the URL somehow (e.g. you need a database or cache or something that maps `my-name-is-ajo` to 2).

Comment: A common approach is to use something like http://localhost:51630/blog/my-name-is-ajo/2 so the URL looks nice at the start, and the ID is at the end.

Comment: how to make that possible any example for that http://localhost:51630/blog/my-name-is-ajo/2 @mjwills

Comment: I found an answer for this solution, and it is working fine, Thanks for your help and advice@mjwills

Comment: i use this code in route.config for finding the solution `routes.MapRoute(
                name: "forblogcontent",
                url: "Blog/{slug}/{id}", 
                defaults: new
                {
                    controller = "Blog",
                    action = "DisplayContent",
                    slug = UrlParameter.Optional
                }   
                );`

Comment: Perfect - great work!